# Unix ODBC Connect 2016 MS SQL Server sql state 28000 native error 18456

Tags: sql-server, linux, unix, odbc, rhel7

I can connect ms sql server on windows desktop using ODBC and I got into the issue when using Linux. ODBC drivers are already installed just that I couldn't connect. I search on the internet and most posts are saying it's windows authentication issue. I set the `Trusted_Connection=No` and enter UID/PWD in `isql -v MSSQL [UID] [PWD]`.

It gives me the error saying:

```
[28000][unixODBC][Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for user 'UID'.
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

The ODBC config file:

```
[root@IRISOEL01 etc]# cat odbcinst.ini
[ODBC]
Trace = Yes
TraceFile = /tmp/trace.log


[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.1.0
UsageCount=3


[root@IRISOEL01 etc]# cat odbc.ini
[MSSQL]
Driver=ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Server=server_address
Database=master
AnsiNPW=Yes
QuotedId=Yes
AutoTranslate=Yes
Trusted_Connection=No
Encrypt=No
```

Answer (score 0):

I just can tell you to try using in odbc.ini the name of the driver you configured in odbcinst.ini

```
Driver=ODBC
```

After adding the driver path in odbcinst.ini, for example I use this odbcinst.ini

```
[SQLServer]
Description=Microsoft SQL Server ODBC Driver V1.0 for Linux
Driver=/opt/microsoft/sqlncli/lib64/libsqlncli-11.0.so.1790.0
Threading=1
UsageCount=1
```

then in odbc.ini

```
[source]
Driver=SQLServer
Description=ODBC Database Connection
Trace=No
Server=192.168.1.25,1433
Database=dbname
```